# Sorting a compound range that includes a query

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, importrange

I'm creating a set of process tracking sheets that allows multiple locations to reprioritize their areas by the amount of work left to do in each one, and then feed process updates from those up to a master tracker.

Wondering if there's any way to sort a larger range that includes a query?

Eg, something like:

```
=sort({query(data, "select *"), D:L}, 2, FALSE)
```

The idea is that when the amount of remaining work is updated via the query, the entire range A:L sorts as a result. The contents of columns outside the query need to move with the area ID.

Here's an example sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1x4f0g38NsKXjCfg-Z4OY9arprefzPE3a6UNMXrbO6H0/edit?usp=sharing

The big restriction here is that these sheets need to involve as little work as possible for the end-user - basically, I want them to update remaining work dynamically and all the end-user has to do is check the Shift boxes.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can do it but it won't make sense if the query would be ordered because it would shift adjacent columns in havoc so the query formula would need to be static and then sort it as a whole body like:

```
=QUERY({data!A4:B12, C4:H12}, "order by Col2 desc", 0)
```

[image: 0]

and **A4** is:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(data!A4:B12)
```

or directly:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("ID", "Sheet1!A4:B12")
```